# ZendFramework 2 : Set date_default_timezone

Tags: php, date, zend-framework2

I am new to the Zend Framework 2 and would like to simply know if there is a global way of setting the date default timezone.

I am aware that i should just be able to add the code:

```
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
```

However i have been looking for about an hour and can't find an answer addressing this issue.

I have also tried by setting this in the php.ini but i'm not sure if this would suppress the error message.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to set it in your php.ini file. This will be for php wide (both web and cli), for all applications and directly available. The timezone of php should be a server wide setting, so it is not strange to put it in a server wide config (the php.ini) as well.

Search for `date.timezone` in your php.ini. You can read more about it [in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone). An example is `date.timezone = UTC`.

Comment: I have tried this then restarted apache and this didn't do anything.

Comment: There are a few things that could go wrong: is the `date.timezone` commented out (ie there is a `#` or a `;` in front of it)? Or, are you using the right php.ini file? Try to create a file with `phpinfo()` in it. View it with your web browser and localize the part where it tells you which php.ini file location is used. The point is: this directive should work (check other online sources) but there might go something wrong in your config. Are you using Apache with MAMP, LAMP or WAMP or a custom install?

Comment: nope the line isn't commented out. and it's the right php.ini file as i recently added imagick to it and that previews on the phpinfo(); also i'm using centos (my testing pc) with apache installed onto it with only the one vhost at current

Answer (score 5):

My "elegant way" is overwriting php settings from config file using onBootstrap. Inside my global.php I add the php settings I need to set up for the app:

```
return array(
   'php_settings' => array(
       'date.timezone' => 'UTC',
       'memory_limit' => '128M',
       'display_errors' =>'On'
   )
);
```

Then, onBootstrap:

```
    //Enable php settings from config file into the web app
    $services = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
    $config = $services->get('config');        
    $phpSettings = $config['php_settings'];
    if ($phpSettings) {
        foreach ($phpSettings as $key => $value) {
            ini_set($key, $value);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I simply add that PHP code in my `public/index.php` file where Zend Framework gets kicked off, or early on in the `application/Bootstrap.php` process. That ensures it is global, and occurs before any application date calls are used.

Comment: If this is the only way of doing i thought they may have added a more elegant way of doing this. Thank you for your input

Answer (score 1):

In Module.php in your onBootstrap function add `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');` Work's for me.

Answer (score 0):

Example for Module.php with Authentication (assuming identity has properties of timezone and locale):

```
class Module {
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e) {
    //...your stuff

    //set the timezone
    $identity = $e->getApplication()
        ->getServiceManager()
        ->get('Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService')
        ->getIdentity();

    if ($identity) {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, $identity->getLocale());
        date_default_timezone_set($identity->getTimezone());
    }
}
```